# Wordpress WP-GCM plugin does not sending new post notification

Tags: wordpress

In Wordpress - WP-GCM plugin does not sending any push notification when publishing a new post or updating a previous one. It sending only message. Anyone please provide solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

This is because the app is configured only to receive "message" and send a notification. The tag for when publishing a new post is "new_post" and for updating a previous one is "update" (Ref: Wordpress GCM documentation). You have to configure the app to receive notifications for this.

Currently it will look something like this in android:

```
newms = extras.getString("message").toString();
sendNotification(newms);
```

You have to add something like:

```
newms = extras.getString("new_post").toString();
newms = extras.getString("update").toString();
sendNotification(newms);
```